# Node: How to avoid hardcoding URLs in views?

Tags: node.js, url, hyperlink, pug, hardcode

I need to avoid writing hardcoding URls in Node apps(code or views).
Is there a package?

Now I write in Jade:

`a(href='/account/profile') Profile`

Profile url is hardcoded.
I need something like this:

`a(href=links.accounts.profile()) Profile`

It will be very useful when I will change URLs. I need to be able to change URLs just from a config file, not from all views...

Comment: Solution must work and for external, static files not just for app routes. For example, if I change host for static resources I need change just host in config/setup - not in all views!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package - [reversable-router.](https://github.com/web-napopa/node-reversable-router)

Example from their readme:

```
app.get('/admin/user/:id', 'admin.user.edit', function(req, res, next){
    //...
});

//.. and a helper in the view files:
url('admin.user.edit', {id: 2})
```

Comment: This method is hard-coded too. But is a nice method.